# How do you properly distribute children?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, genetic-algorithm

I have an array of parents that I want to make babies, and an empty array (of which I need to be a fixed length) waiting to be filled.

I need babies - children - to be evenly distributed based on how handsome their dad is; however, I need everyone to get a clone incase their mutated child is uglier / beautifuller, then theres another chance...(`parents.length <= children.length`)

The parent array is sorted by handsomeness, so `parents[0] = me;`. 
What I've done so far is:

```
for (var p = parents.legth; parent--;) {
    var myself = parents[p],
        aRandomDaddy = parents[~~(Math.random()*parents.length)]
        iDeserveMoreThan1Child = parents.length-p;
        // if this is 0 they're last in the array and just get their 1 clone. Should be different, right?

    makeABabyWith(myself);
    if (iDeserveMoreThan1Child) {
        makeABabyWith(aRandomDaddy);
    }
}
```

What I'm now trying to do is figure out a way to algorithmically `makeABabyWith(aRandomDaddy)`, `children.length - parents.length` times, and take into account how handsome the daddies are.

I've thought of doing:

```
for(var c = parents.length, totalHandsomeness = 0; c--;)
    totalHandsomeness+= parents[c].handsomeness;
...

    makeABabyWith(myself);
    for (var handsomenessComparedToEveryoneElse
         = ~~(myself.handsomeness * children.length / totalHandsomeness);
         handsomenessComparedToEveryoneElse--;) {
        makeABabyWith(aRandomDaddy);
    }
...
```

Now this gives a distribution relative to their percantage, of the parents.
However when the flooring occurs you'll sometimes get 0.
So if the children array is of length 20, you're offspring can range very widely.

One way I thought of countering this is to iteritively run this foreloop, something like this:

```
...
var childrenToBeCreated = children.length - parents.length;
...

    makeABabyWith(myself);

    while (childrenToBeCreated) for (var handsomenessComparedToEveryoneElse
         = ~~(myself.handsomeness * children.length / totalHandsomeness);
        handsomenessComparedToEveryoneElse--;) {
        if (childrenToBeCreated) {
            makeABabyWith(aRandomDaddy);
            childrenToBeCreated--;
        } else break;
    }

//EDIT: realised this would run to the end in the first loop and break, instead of run through all and check for left overs.
//EDIT OF THE EDIT: no it wouldn't...
//ED...: Yes it would, the while loops inside the for loop.
...

console.log("is","this"+"a good way to do it?? would this even work");
```

Although this is written in JS its the exact same principle in any language.

Is the method I thought up while writing this question sufficient, and how would you do it?

Edit: The last example was meant to use Percentages of `childrenToBeCreated` not `ptotal`, I think I got confused.

Comment: `How do you properly distribute children?`  That sounds more like a legal question rather than a programming one.  Sounds a bit morally dubious as well.

Comment: I had to upvote this Question, and your comment @SamAxe. The premise is histerical. Lol `I need babies`. LOL  The parent array is sorted by handsomeness, so `parents[0] = me`

Comment: This whole question is secretly a trafficking advert.

Comment: You realize your software is *never* going to work, right?  All the parents are daddies.. and while that may be acceptable socially in some places.. its a reproductive impossibility no matter your location, politics, morality, etc.

Comment: It's 2016, there's surely some expensive form of surgery that'll get these daddies sorted.

Comment: Maybe, but if this software is the surgeon they'll probably end up with some half-cat-human-hybrid for a child.. and then how would they score on the handsomeness chart?

Comment: I almost spit my coffee on the screen when reading the title. LOL.

Comment: @SamAxe Thats where the clone comes in. Dolly the sheep was pretty successful.

Comment: `makeABabyWith(aRandomDaddy)` See this is the problem with today's society

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the legal implications of this question you should contact a lawyer, but I think I can help you with the technical aspects of the problem ;)

Blueprints for the factories on Kamino (alpha stadium):

```
var int = v => 0|v;

//creates mostly average and below values, and fewer high values
var randomHandsomeness = () => int( Math.pow(Math.random(), 2) * 100 ) + 1;

var breedClone = (parent) => ({ 
    id: int(Math.random() * 0x80000000).toString(36),  //no time for names
    handsomeness: int( .25 * parent.handsomeness + .75 * randomHandsomeness() ), //a bit genetic heritage but mostly luck
    parent: parent //just for the record
});

var deriveBatch = (parents, numClonesToBreed, minChildrenPerParent, distribution) => {
    console.log("starting batch of", numClonesToBreed);

    if(typeof minChildrenPerParent === "function"){
        distribution = minChildrenPerParent;
        minChildrenPerParent = 0;
    }

    if(typeof distribution !== "function"){
        distribution = (handsomeness) => handsomeness;
    }

    minChildrenPerParent = Math.max(int(minChildrenPerParent), 0);

    //I'll add these back in the loop
    numClonesToBreed -= parents.length * minChildrenPerParent; 
    if(numClonesToBreed < 0){
        throw new Error("increase batch size, insufficient capacities for these specs");
    }

    //order doesn't matter, only handsomeness in relation to the total handsomeness
    var totalHandsomeness = parents.reduce((acc, p) => acc + distribution( p.handsomeness ), 0); 

    return parents.reduce((newBatch, parent) => {   
        //this computation doesn't only compute the relative handsomeness of the parent to the group,
        //and the amount of children he's entitled to, but also balances the delta 
        //between the computed value and the rounded numChildren
        //(partial clones are of no use and are therefore avoided).
        //At the same time it's important to neither overproduce nor stay short of the goal.
        var handsomeness = distribution( parent.handsomeness );
        var numChildren = Math.round( handsomeness / totalHandsomeness * numClonesToBreed );
        totalHandsomeness -= handsomeness;
        numClonesToBreed -= numChildren;

        //add the minimum amount of children per parent to the computed/distributed numChildren
        numChildren += minChildrenPerParent;
        console.log("handsomeness: %i, children: %i", parent.handsomeness, numChildren);

        while(numChildren--) newBatch.push( breedClone( parent ) );
        return newBatch;
    }, []);
}
```

Let the production begin:

```
//prepare a first batch
var parents = deriveBatch([{
    id: "Jango Fett",
    handsomeness: 75,
    parent: null //file corrupted
}], 10);

//breed new clones from the parent batch
//create 30 clones
//create at least 1 clone per parent
//and a weighting function how the handsomeness impacts the amount of children
//pow < 1: handsome people get more children, but not that much more
//pow = 1: linear correlation of handsomeness to distribution
//pow > 1: handsome people get significantly more children
var children = deriveBatch(parents, 30, 1, handsomeness => Math.pow(handsomeness, 1.25));
```

**Disclaimer:** This facility is not liable for any actions performed by the produced clones under any foreign command.

I think most of the code should explain itself, and should be easily ported/applied to your codebase. Added a few hooks and configs to be able to manipulate the behaviour/distribution of the algo.

Comment: Great solution, it's really elegant

Comment: Can you do "%i" type replacement in javascript / console.log()? Or is it an ES6 feature as I noticed you used some lambda functions.

Comment: @Tobiq [MDN: Console Using_string_substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Using_string_substitutions)